# Missing datetime.time.__sub__?

Tags: python, datetime, time, missing-features

Why can't subtract two time objects? For example, 12:00 - 11:00 = 1:00

```
from datetime import time
time(12,00) - time(11,00) # -> timedelta(hours=1)
```

It seems that `datetime.time.__sub__` is missing

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

do you know why?

Comment: Could be an oversight, or could be overthinking--the author going "in this case it's ambiguous, so we shouldn't implement it at all", rather than simply clearly *defining* the case.  Nobody but the designer can do any more than guess at the actual rationale, but I agree this is an obviously missing operation.  Anyway, there's a lot more wrong with the datetime module in Python than this (the timezone stuff is beyond braindamaged)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `time` objects have no date, so for example, the `12:00` might be (say) on a Wed and the `11:00` on the preceding Tue, making the difference 25 hours, not one (any multiple of 24 might be added or subtracted).  If you know they're actually on the same date, just apply any arbitrary date to each of them (making two `datetime` objects) and *then* you'll be able to subtract them.  E.g.:

```
import datetime

def timediff(t1, t2):
  td = datetime.date.today()
  return datetime.datetime.combine(td, t1) - datetime.datetime.combine(td, t2)
```

Comment: yes, this is a trick... but I continue to understand why <pre>__sub__</pre> is not implemented: it is obvious that the two time refer to same day, otherwise I should have used datetime.datetime.

For example datasheet software do this (excel)

Comment: Maybe obvious to you, but not to everyone. It's easier to not support it now, allow support for it in the future, and not have to live with a possibly-bad choice now.

Comment: This is kind of related to how you cannot modify a datetime.time() object with a datetime.timedelta() object. As Alex says, not having a date component means that you do not know if they are on the same day. Similarly, if you add/subtract a timedelta, it may push the time onto another day (overflow), and there is no way to know this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result by

```
t1 = time(12, 0)
t2 = time(11, 0)
td = timedelta(hours=t1.hour-t2.hour, minutes=t1.minute-t2.minute)
```

Comment: ok, of course, but I want to understand why the __sub__ method is not implemented